# upload project to shared hosting in yii2

Tags: php, yii2

please guide me guys to upload advanced project with frontend and backend to shared hosting online!
I confused with directory structure and i read the [yii2](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-tutorial-shared-hosting.html)

[image: this is ok?]

how about **remove backend/web and frontend/web**?

**UPdated Part!**
[image: pulic_html folder]

[image: root]

```
defined('YII_DEBUG') or define('YII_DEBUG', true);
defined('YII_ENV') or define('YII_ENV', 'dev');

 require(__DIR__ . '../vendor/autoload.php');
 require(__DIR__ . '../vendor/yiisoft/yii2/Yii.php');
 require(__DIR__ . '../common/config/bootstrap.php');
 require(__DIR__ . '../frontend/config/bootstrap.php');

$config = yii\helpers\ArrayHelper::merge(
    require(__DIR__ . '/../common/config/main.php'),
    require(__DIR__ . '/../common/config/main-local.php'),
    require(__DIR__ . '/../frontend/config/main.php'),
  require(__DIR__ . '/../frontend/config/main-local.php')
);

 $application = new yii\web\Application($config);
 $application->run();
```

Comment: what do you don't undertsand?

Comment: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-tutorial-shared-hosting.html Read the docs!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's important to understand the principles behind what you're trying to achieve here.

Basically, the contents of the folders frontend/web and backend/web are the only parts of yii that should be in a publicly accessible folder. In your case, this is your public_html folder. Thus, the document you have read says to move the contents of frontend/web into your public_html folder, and backend/web into a new folder you have to create, public_html/admin. Note that you need to move the contents of the folders, not the folders themselves.

Next, you need to move all of the rest of the yii application to somewhere it's not readable by public. This is for security reasons. Hence, the document you read says to copy frontend and backend folders from your local machine into folders that are above your public_html folder.

It seems complicated, but it's not really. You just end up with a directory structure something like this. It's difficult to draw a directory structure here, but I'll do my best!

```
--backend (everything else from backend goes in here)
--etc
--frontend (everything else from frontend goes in here)
--logs
--mail
--public_html (all the contents of frontend/web go in here)
----admin (all the contents of backend/web go in here)
```

After that you will need to open the index.php files in each of public_html and public_html/admin and alter the paths that tell yii where to find the key startup scripts. Point them to the new folders you created.

Comment: @Miller are you sure ? coz i did exactly as you set but when call the site blank page show!

Comment: Yes, I'm sure, this is exactly the setup I have on my own sites, and it works for loads of other sites that use Yii. You must have made some mistake in following the instructions given. What we have to find out is what mistake you have made. You will need to give more information! Can you update your question with a new screenshot of your file structure?

Comment: Oh, and can you also add the contents of your index.php file from the frontend? Thanks!

Comment: `[Sat Dec 12 23:09:42 2015] [error] [client 5.250.61.30] client denied by server configuration: /home/aznaston/public_html/admin/index.cgi` server error and show blank page!

Comment: @Miller im realy appreciate for your answer!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97740/discussion-between-joe-miller-and-mohsen).